# Bind 9 debug logging requests from localhost

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, bind, localhost

If I do, for example
dig delfi.lv
from a PC on LAN, I get some log messages in /var/cache/bind/named.run like:

29-Oct-2020 12:01:51.905 client @0x7f2adc000cd0 192.168.1.2#37827 (delfi.lv): query: delfi.lv IN A +E(0) (192.168.1.1)

But if I do the same request from localhost (the server itself) I get the same answer, but no messages in the log file. How to fix it?

Comment: Was the query sent to the same server in the "testing locally" case?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I started getting log entries on some requests, but there is still an issue. If I do "dig PC" on localhost, where PC is 192.168.1.2, I don't get a response and no log entries, but if I do "ping PC", ping works and at the same moment I get DNS requests of PC from localhost in the log.

Comment: I get response, if I do "dig PC.lan". I have "search lan" in /etc/resolv.conf, so both should work, right?

Comment: Does `dig +search PC` work?

Comment: New day, new issue. None of "dig PC", "dig PC.lan", "dig +search PC" work. But if I query the external name, like "dig delfi.lv", it works. I have seen this before. If I restart the server, it works again.

Comment: "ping PC" returns "ping: PC: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Comment: When dig was failing, systemd-resolved was printing "Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP." After restarting systemd-resolved "dig PC.lan" and "dig +search PC" works, but "dig PC" doesn't. No error from systemd-resolved.